# What argument is being passed to this function?

Tags: python, pandas, function

Considering a function (apply_this_function) that will be applied to a dataframe:

```
# our dataset
data = {"addresses": ['Newport Beach, California', 'New York City', 'London, England', 10001, 'Sydney, Au']}

# create a throw-away dataframe
df_throwaway = df.copy()

def apply_this_function(passed_row):
    passed_row['new_col'] = True
    passed_row['added'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    return passed_row


df_throwaway.apply(apply_this_function, axis=1) # axis=1 is important to use the row itself
```

In `df_throway.appy(.)`, where does the function take the "passed_row" parameter? Or what value is this function taking? My assumption is that by the structure of apply(), the function takes values from row i starting at 1?

I am referring to the information obtained [here](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/api-calls-pandas-dataframe-pd-apply)

Comment: When in doubt look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). _Result of applying func along the given axis of the DataFrame._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply a function to a DataFrame with *axis=1*, then
this function is called for each row from the source DataFrame
and by convention its parameter is called *row*.

In your case this function returns (from each call) the original
row (actually a *Series* object), with 2 new elements added.

Then *apply* method collects these rows, concatenates them
and the result is a DataFrame with 2 new columns.

You wrote *takes values from row i starting at 1*. I would change it to
*takes values from each row*.
Writing *starting at 1* can lead to misunderstandings, since when your
DataFrame has a default index, its values start from **0** (not from *1*).

In addition, I would like to propose 2 corrections to your code:

1. Create your DataFrame passing *data* (your code sample does not
   contain creation of *df*):

   ```
    df_throwaway = pd.DataFrame(data)
   ```
2. Define your function as:

   ```
   def apply_this_function(row):
       row['new_col'] = True
       row['added'] = pd.Timestamp.now()
       return row
   ```

   i.e.:

   - name the parameter as just *row* (everybody knows that this row
     has been *passed* by *apply* method),
   - instead of *datetime.datetime.now()* use *pd.Timestamp.now()*
     i.e. a native *pandasonic* type and its method.